# Export Data Frame or Print to CSV

Tags: r

I' trying to export data that is printed to .csv but am unable to figure out the appropriate syntax/code to do so.

```
for (project in 1:ncol(df)){
  i=1
  for (digs in c(df[, project])){
    total[i,project] = getTotalDigsCost(digs)
    i = i +1
  }
}

data.frame(average = sapply(total, mean),
           sd = sapply(total, sd),
           p95 = sapply(total, function(x) quantile(x,.95)),
           p20 = sapply(total, function(x) quantile(x,.20)),
           p80 = sapply(total, function(x) quantile(x,.80)))

write_csv(total, "1_R_DigsCostOutput.csv")
```

I can use the command `write_csv(total, 1"1_R-DigsCostOutput.csv")` to export `total`, but I can't identify what to write to export the values of `sd`, `p95`, etc.

Thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you just write the entire dataframe to the csv?

Comment: You need to give that data.frame a name and then just save it the same way.  `df <- data.frame(average=..., etc); write_csv(df,"filename.csv")`

Comment: Thank you Andrew & Mr. Bugle! I figured it out with your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Mr. Bugle and Andrew in the comments above, I found a solution to exporting the data frame:

```
write_csv(data.frame(average = sapply(total, mean),
                     sd = sapply(total, sd),
                     p95 = sapply(total,function(x) quantile(x,.95)),
                     p20 = sapply(total, function(x) quantile(x,.20)),
                     p80 = sapply(total, function(x) quantile(x,.80))),"1_R_Digs.csv")
```